# Some basic properties of Pisot number

Tags: number-theory

A Pisot number is  an algebraic integer $>1 $ and all of whose conjugates have modulus $<1$.   First assume that $q$ is  a Pisot number. Denote by $q_1,\ldots, q_d$ the algebraic conjugates of $q$.  Let $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\epsilon_i x^i$ be a polynomial with coefficients in $\{0, \pm 1,\ldots, \pm m\}$. Suppose that $P(q)\neq 0$. Then $P(q_j)\neq 0$ for $1\leq j\leq d$, and $P(q)\prod_{j=1}^dP(q_j)$ is a non-zero integer

How can we prove this result?

Comment: you can consider some simple case, for example the golden mean and it can give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) says that a symmetric polynomial $Q(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb Z[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ is a polynomial in the [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n$, i.e. $Q(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=R(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ for a polynomial $R\in\mathbb Z[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$.

The polynomial $P(q)\prod_{i=1}^dP(q_i)$ is symmetric in $q,q_1,\ldots,q_d$, therefore $P(q)\prod_{i=1}^dP(q_i)=R(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n,\sigma_{n+1})$ for a polynomial $R\in\mathbb Z[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}]$. Since $\sigma_i$, the elementary symmetric polynomials on $q,q_1,\ldots,q_d$, are the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $q$ (here we use the fact that $q$ is an algebraic integer) it follows that $\sigma_i$ are integers (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials#Properties)). Therefore $P(q)\prod_{i=1}^dP(q_i)=R(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n,\sigma_{n+1})\in\mathbb Z$.

As Gerry Myerson said this has nothing to do with Pisot numbers. It is true for any algebraic integer.

Comment: you should say it is non-zero integer.

Comment: @Tao: I think this follow easily from the fact that $P(q)\neq0, P(q_i)\neq0, \ \forall i=1,2,\ldots, d$.

Comment: why can we obtain this result?

Comment: @Tao: What result?

Comment: $P(q)\neq0, P(q_i)\neq0, \ \forall i=1,2,\ldots, d$ and $P(q)\Pi^d_iP(q_i)$ is symmetric

Comment: @Tao: Is a fact that, for an algebraic integer $q=q_0$ with conjucates $q_i, i=1,2,\ldots,d$ if $P(q_j)=0$ for an integer polynomial $P\in\mathbb Z[x]$ and a $j\in\{0,1,\ldots,d\}$ then $P(q_i)=0$ for all $i=0,1,\ldots,d$. For your second question (the symmetry of the polynomial $P(q)...$) see the definition of [symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial).

Comment: now I know that the mutiplication is symmetric because we change the order of $q_i$ and it do not change the value.

Answer (score 2):

The result you ask about has nothing to do with Pisot numbers --- it is true for any algebraic integer. If a polynomial with integer coefficients vanishes at some algebraic number $\alpha$, then the polynomial is a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, so it vanishes at all the conjugates of $\alpha$. And the product of $P(\beta)$ over all the conjugates $\beta$ of $\alpha$ (including $\beta=\alpha$) is an algebraic integer, and is fixed by the Galois group of the rationals adjoin all the conjugates, so it's rational, so it's an integer.

Comment: it seems a little difficult to understand, could you please give some detailed information?

Comment: What do you know about algebraic integers? about Galois Theory? (If the answer is, "not much", then you are in over your head, and I'd need to write a book to answer your question to your satisfaction).

Comment: I totally do not know Galois Theory and only know if an algebraic number is rational then it is an integer.